# Algo me deniega el acceso a una descarga por http

Tags: java

para explicaros un poco es un proyecto propio con muchas clases propias probadas y las uno todas para conseguir un checqueo de arhivos y una descarga de un servidor que da una version de app, esta se compara con la version de app local y si no coincide porque hay una mas moderna pues procede bajar un zip y descomprimirlo.
os dejo el codigo

```
package MAin;

import checkingFile.CheckingFile;
import updateCheker.ConnectionToServer;
import updateCheker.UpdateChecker;
import javax.swing.*;

import BasePathManager.BasePathManager;
import DownloadUpdate.DownloadUpdate;
import UnZip.ManejoArchivosComprimidos;

import java.io.*;

public class MainFileCreateAndUpdate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        String[] DocumentosNecesario = {
            "config/config.txt",
            "log/log.txt",
            "data/usr/data.txt",
            "myUpdate/",
            "version.txt"
        };
        BasePathManager mainPath = new BasePathManager();
        String updateFolder = "C:\\Users\\stevefletesalfaro\\Desktop\\Eclipseproyecto\\moduloFileCreationAndUpdate\\myUpdate" + File.separator;
        
        CheckingFile chequeo = new CheckingFile(DocumentosNecesario);
        chequeo.chequearYCrearDocumentos();

        File archivoVersion = new File("version.txt");

        UpdateChecker leerVersion = new UpdateChecker();
        ConnectionToServer conectarServidor = new ConnectionToServer();
        double versionLocal = leerVersion.obtenerNumeroActualizacion("version.txt");
        double versionServidor = conectarServidor.ConnectToServer("10.211.55.4:8000");

        if (versionLocal < versionServidor) {
            try (FileWriter escribir = new FileWriter(archivoVersion, false)) { // false para sobrescribir
                escribir.write(String.valueOf(versionServidor));
                escribir.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Actualización disponible. Descargando...");


            String fileURL = "http://10.211.55.4:8000/" + (int) versionServidor + ".zip";
            String saveDir = updateFolder;
            DownloadUpdate descargar = new DownloadUpdate();
            descargar.DownloadFiles(fileURL, saveDir);

            String direccionArchivoZip = saveDir + File.separator + (int) versionServidor + ".zip";
            String descompresionCarpeta = mainPath.getBasePath() + File.separator;
            ManejoArchivosComprimidos unzipper = new ManejoArchivosComprimidos();
            try {
                unzipper.descomprimir(direccionArchivoZip, descompresionCarpeta);
                System.out.println("Descompresión completada.");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error al descomprimir el archivo: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Tienes la última versión.");
        }
    }
}
```

el codigo da este resultado del servidor y este codigo de error local que no he conseguido solucionar, y creo que no tiene nada que ver con el propio codigo o hay algo que se me escapa.

```
l documento ya existe: config/config.txt
El documento ya existe: log/log.txt
El documento ya existe: data/usr/data.txt
El documento ya existe: myUpdate/
El documento ya existe: version.txt
Respuesta de servidor: 200
1126
Error al descargar el archivo: C:\Users\stevefletesalfaro\Desktop\Eclipseproyecto\moduloFileCreationAndUpdate\myUpdate (Acceso denegado)
Error al descomprimir el archivo: C:\Users\stevefletesalfaro\Desktop\Eclipseproyecto\moduloFileCreationAndUpdate\myUpdate\1126.zip (El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado)
```

voy a aclarar primero lo que hice para solucionar brevemente, he intentado ponerle permisos de ejecución, escritura y lectura. he abierto eclipse como administrador y en modo compatibilidad. desactivado el antivirus y el UAC. y sigue dando el mismo error.
también me gastaría dejar claro que lo hago en una maquina vitual de parallels en un mac con procesador arm.
si alguien sabe algo lo agradeceria.

Comment: ¡Nunca coloques información sensible en un sitio público! Cuando muestres código, recuerda siempre enmascarar información tal como IP, correos electrónicos, números de teléfono entre otros.

Comment: Varias cosas raras.. primero, si la ip es valida y publica, habria que eliminarla y tenes que avisar que la hiciste publica... Aparte de eso, cuando descargas algo, tenes que esperar a que descargue... termino de descargar????

Comment: la ip no es real, ni los nombres es una máquina virtual totalmente aislada en una red local